# overloading operators when using setOldClass not works as wanted compared to an S4 class

Tags: r, r-s4

Can someone explain why overloading an operator on an old-style S3 class which is registered does not work as expected while when defining a new class and overloading the operators does work.

As shown in the following examples.

This does not work.

```
require(ff) 
setOldClass(Classes=c("ff_vector")) 
setMethod( 
  f="*", 
  signature = signature(e1 = c("ff_vector"), e2 = c("ff_vector")), 
  definition = function (e1, e2){ 
        print("S3 setOldClass")
        e1[] * e2[] 
    } 
) 
ff(1:10) * ff(1:10) 
Error in ff(1:10) * ff(1:10) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

But this works.

```
setClass("myff_vector", representation(x="ff_vector"))
setMethod( 
  f="*", 
  signature = signature(e1 = c("myff_vector"), e2 = c("myff_vector")), 
  definition = function (e1, e2){ 
        print("S4 setOldClass")
        e1@x[] * e2@x[] 
    } 
) 
new("myff_vector", x = ff(1:10)) * new("myff_vector", x = ff(1:10))
[1] "S4 setOldClass"
[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the same issue behind this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55019663/non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-when-defining-a-data-frame-method-for/55021034#55021034] question (the objects themselves need to be S4, in the sense of `isS4()` on at least one of them needs to be TRUE, and `setOldClass` is not sufficient for that).

Answer (score 0):

Attempt at a partial answer:
In help('Methods'), in the **Generic Functions** section, it is stated:

> Methods may be defined for most primitives, and corresponding metadata
>   objects will be created to store them. Calls to the primitive still go
>   directly to the C code, which will sometimes check for applicable
>   methods. The definition of “sometimes” is that methods must have been
>   detected for the function in some package loaded in the session and
>   **isS4(x) is TRUE** for the first argument (or for the second argument, in
>   the case of binary operators).

Back to your problem, `*` is a primitive, and:

```
library(ff)
setOldClass("ff_vector")
isS4(ff(1:10))
[1] FALSE
```

So from what I understand, it is not possible to define a method for primitive functions on S3 classes, even if you use setOldClass().

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear from the question whether this counts as an answer, but for the record, the operator could be overloaded in plain and simple S3-style, without any `setOldClass` or `S4`:

```
`*.ff_vector` <- function(x, y) {
  print("hi")
  x[] * y[]
}

> ff(1:10) * ff(1:10)
[1] "hi"
[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```