# non-numeric argument to binary operator when defining a data.frame method for `+` and using on ggplot object

Tags: r, class, ggplot2, methods, r-s4

I can define a S3 method like this :

```
`+.data.frame` <- function(e1,e2){"hello"}
iris + iris
# [1] "hello"
```

But this won't work if `e2` is a `gg` object :

```
iris + geom_point()
```

> Error in iris + geom_point() : non-numeric argument to binary operator
>
> In addition: Warning message: Incompatible methods ("+.data.frame",
>   "+.gg") for "+"

I think it has something to do with S4 methods but I'm confused. Can you explain what's at play and how to sort it out ?

desired output :

```
iris + geom_point()
# [1] "hello"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not due to S4 methods but a method conflict. Neither `geom_point()` nor your data frame are S4 objects (`isS4` on either of them returns FALSE), so S4 methods will not come into play.

The `ggplot` package defines a method for `+` on `gg`-classed objects, and you have just defined a method for `data.frame`s. The trouble is, unlike most S3 generic functions, `+` takes the class of *both* arguments into account in selecting a method. In this case, it concludes that it could have legitimately chosen the `gg` method as well as the `data.table` method.

From the help page for "Ops" (of which "+" is a member):

> The classes of both arguments are considered in dispatching any member of this group. For each argument its vector of classes is examined to see if there is a matching specific (preferred) or Ops method. If a method is found for just one argument or the same method is found for both, it is used. If different methods are found, there is a warning about ‘incompatible methods’: in that case or if no method is found for either argument the internal method is used.

So you see in this case, it falls through to the default `+` code, which doesn't know how to add data frames and `gg` objects, and returns an error saying as much.

To solve the issue, you may be able to write an S4 method with signature `(data.frame,gg)` (or perhaps `(data.frame,ANY)` but beware — it will only actually be called if one of the arguments is an S4 object (which data.frames are not by default). You may have to define your own class which contains `data.frame` (or, alternatively, contains `gg`) in order to trigger the method.

Comment: clear answer thanks! so in short, not possible unless I overwrite the default method, which is not advisable, and in that case I would still get a warning.

Comment: In this situation I would advise using S4, in which you can specify the classes of both arguments explicitly. But be careful, S4 methods only get called on "+" if one of the arguments is S4. Have updated answer to include this info.

Comment: See also this thread: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/quot-Incompatible-methods-quot-for-overloaded-operator-td4633362.html which adds some details about potentially converting to S4