# Times New Roman as default font in the Project

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to find a solution on the internet, how to define Times New Roman as default font in the R project under Windows 10.

I have a script that load a lots of scripts inside. Therefore, I used

```
windowsFonts(A = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))  # Specify font
plot(data$x,                                      # Plot with manually specified font
     data$y,
     family = "A")
```

It changed once, but after that I get an error message:

```
Error in tm_shape(baza) + tm_polygons("PosetaNa1Stanovnika", palette =
"-BuGn",  :    non-numeric argument to binary operator In addition:
Warning message: In eval(ei, envir) : Incompatible methods ("+.tmap",
"+.gg") for "+"
```

How to solve a problem?
Thanks

One solution that I found is [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55021034/11955574) but I can not even check  "Disable .Rprofile execution on session start/resume" and "Quit child processes on exit"

Comment: Hi there @aleksandar_m, it looks like your problem has to to with mixing `tmap` and `ggplot2` objects within a `+` operation rather than the font. However it's not possible to reproduce this from the code you shared. It might help to get this problem into a minimal reproducible example, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) for a nice guide on how to do this, best wishes.

Comment: @Coy, is there any solution to define Times New Roman as default font face family?